# Hue Sessions Statistics Details

Tags: hadoop, hue

is there any command to check how many hue sessions are currently running in Hadoop and any way to view the sessions that have been running along with their age?

Answer (score 0):

A jira that is going to help with this is [HUE-2288 Expose perf metrics](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2288)